# При масштабировании карты возникают ошибки API Яндекса Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentState' of null

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

После вывода карты с кластерами, если изменять масштаб карты, где-то в трети случаях карта подвисает, в консоль браузера выводятся ошибки API ЯндексКарты:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentState' of null

Причем количество ошибок увеличивается, при прокрутке колеса мыши (при попытке масштабирования.

Ссылка на проект http://ikvo.ru/maps/volg_map.php

> ------------------- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>       at Object._getPosition (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.68/combine.js? .... callback_prefix=__jsonp_ymaps_combine&mode=release&load=_)   at
>   Object._getPosition
>   (api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.68/combine.js?callback_prefix=__jsonp_ymaps_combine&mode=release&load=_)
>   ....

Answer (score 2):

В файле с метками, который вы загружаете, есть невалидные координаты.

Comment: Да, при проверке xml с координатами, нашлись точки с отсутствующими координатами. Спасибо огромное!